# Oracle Update Statement clarification required

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms

I am updating a table based on values from another table using the Serial Number field as the common field to look up values. However from below 2 queries i get two different results. Can some one explain why the two outputs are different? Should not the update statement update 47200 records?

```
UPDATE TBL_SERIAL_NUMBER_MASTER A
SET (A.name) = (SELECT B.name 
                FROM TBL_DEVICE_LOCALITY B 
                WHERE A.SERIAL_NUMBER = B.SERIAL_NUMBER AND ROWNUM <=1 )
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
               FROM TBL_DEVICE_LOCALITY 
               WHERE SERIAL_NUMBER = A.SERIAL_NUMBER 
                AND TBL_ODIN_DEVICE_LOCALITY.HOST_NAME IS NOT NULL );
```

Results int: 35,311 rows updated.

```
select count(*)
from TBL_SERIAL_NUMBER_MASTER A, TBL_DEVICE_LOCALITY B
WHERE A.SERIAL_NUMBER = B.SERIAL_NUMBER AND B.HOST_NAME IS NOT NULL;
```

Returns: Count = 47200

Comment: Your first query references the table `TBL_ODIN_DEVICE_LOCALITY` in the subquery.  I assume this is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  So, the second query should be:

```
select count(*)
from TBL_SERIAL_NUMBER_MASTER A JOIN
     TBL_DEVICE_LOCALITY B
     ON A.SERIAL_NUMBER = B.SERIAL_NUMBER 
where B.HOST_NAME IS NOT NULL;
```

You are getting the results you see because the two queries are not the same.  Your results suggests that `SERIAL_NUMBER` is not unique in the `B` table, so the `JOIN` is multiplying rows.  On the other hand, the `UPDATE` is updating rows in `A`, regardless of the number of matches in `B`.

To compare like to like, use:

```
select count(*)
from TBL_SERIAL_NUMBER_MASTER A JOIN
     TBL_DEVICE_LOCALITY B
     ON A.SERIAL_NUMBER = B.SERIAL_NUMBER 
where exists (select 1 
              from TBL_DEVICE_LOCALITY B
              where B.SERIAL_NUMBER = A.SERIAL_NUMBER AND
                    B.HOST_NAME IS NOT NULL
             );
```

Or, if you have a unique/primary key column in `A`, then you can use:

```
select count(distinct A.??)
from TBL_SERIAL_NUMBER_MASTER A JOIN
     TBL_DEVICE_LOCALITY B
     ON A.SERIAL_NUMBER = B.SERIAL_NUMBER 
where B.HOST_NAME IS NOT NULL;
```

Where `??` is the unique/primary key column.